# React-Navigation: Route should declare a screen... error

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am new to react-navigation and I followed the steps on the [site](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/), however I get an error saying Route 'Chat' should declare a screen... Below is my code for reference.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  Text,
  View,
  Button,
} from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Welcome',
  };
  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Hello, Chat App!</Text>
        <Button
          onPress={() => navigate('Chat')}
          title="Chat with Lucy"
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('navigationApp', () => navigationApp);
```

This is where I believe the error is occurring

```
const navigationApp = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
  Chat: { screen: ChatScreen },
});

class ChatScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Chat with Lucy',
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Chat with Lucy</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you test declaring ChatScreen above the navigationApp..

Comment: @NeelGala Thank you, that actually worked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue as yours too here.Well, according to my solution,
what i did is I put the line with:

```
 const navigationApp = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
  Chat: { screen: ChatScreen },
});
```

on top part, just above the AppRegistry... line. It should be in the `index.android.js` file.

And don't forget to include this line at the top of this file too:

```
import { ChatScreen } from './App';
```

And according to the tutorial that you're following(i believe it's the same as what i'm following right here), you should have one other file named 'app.js'; which you're referencing in the import line.

contents of 'app.js':

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
export class ChatScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Chat with Lucy',
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Chat with Lucy</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

That's it. However, it depends on the machine and system you're using. I'm using a MacBook pro with a Mac OS Sierra 10.12.6

And the react-native is also a latest version, not sure if there are more recent versions(there are quite a number of updates from time to time).

Try to modify a line/commands , whichever suits to your versions, and read the examples/tutorials carefully. There could be some deprecated functions/unusable codes, etc., due to some updates/ different system environment.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you have an index.js for your component or directory, don't forget to add the export there too! (Not that I've ever done that....)

A good article about organizing a project is and the use of index.js: [Organizing a React Native Project](https://medium.com/the-react-native-log/organizing-a-react-native-project-9514dfadaa0) on Medium

Answer (score 0):

Put `navigationOptions` into like

```
{screen: ScreenComponent, navigationOptions: ...your options }
```